# Visual Studio 2015 Build Rebuild Clean not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am working on windows services C#, I have commented out a few lines so that i can test specific code, cleaned and rebuild the project successfully, however when i step into the code the commented lines with execute. I have tried to exit visual studio and come back again but the same thing happens.

I deleted the bin directory manually but the same thing happens.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Clearly your code isn't being recompiled, or you are editing the same code in a different location

Answer (score 0):

First Build project in Debug mode then,
You need to replace your new .dll file with previous one in your installation folder or
Once again install your .dll file using Visual Studio Command prompt.
Then Restart your service.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/create-and-install-windows-service-step-by-step-in-C-Sharp/